# Integer Validation not working properly with Data Annotation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have come across this issue a few times now and I can't seem to get the exact answer as to why it is happening.

I have a field that needs to validate the input to only accept integers.

I have the data model property as below:

```
[Display(Name = "Customer ID")]
[Required]
[Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage="Must be integer")]
public int CustId { get; set; }
```

I have the HTML as below. It was generated by the MVC Scaffolding

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

 <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustId)
    </div>
 </div>

...
```

The textbox accepts integers with no error message. When I entered letters/alphabets, the textbox will simply clear its field and shows no error message. However, if I entered numerics followed by letters eg. 1234abcd the textbox will be validated correctly and even show the correct error message.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 and I have JQuery Validation and Unobstructive turned on.

I tried using [DataAnnotationExtension](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/) by adding Integer attribute and I still got the same problem.

It has been pointed out that it is possibly caused by a bug(s) within the JQuery Validation. What exactly is the bug/problem?

Comment: Is it working when you turn off the Jquery unobtrusive validation?

Comment: I have noticed some unusual behaviours. If I turn off Unobstructive, only Integer field gets validated and the Decimal field does not. But the validation is still no working properly just like above. So, does this mean that the validation is done by the View code-behind/data-annotation instead of JQuery?